# Complete Device Bound Notification REST does not work for me

Tags: azure-iot-hub, php-curl, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am calling REST call with PHP-curl to complete the device notification message referred from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/completedeviceboundnotification). below is my code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://MYHUBNAME.azure-devices.net/devices/MYDVCID/messages/deviceBound/DVCTAG?api-version=2018-06-30",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: MYSASTOKEN",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: MYHUBHOST",
    "UserAgent: Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.17.2",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: "
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

In the response, I am always getting the below JSON response

```
{
  "Message": "{"errorCode":400004,"trackingId":"XXXXXXXXX-G:7-TimeStamp:XXXXXXXX","message":"BadRequest","timestampUtc":"XXXXXXXXX"}",
  "ExceptionMessage": ""
}
```

I tried a lot to fix it but not getting the issue, please help me

Comment: Were you able to receive the message using PHP-curl?
What scale tier of IoT Hub are you using- Free, Basic, or Standard?

Comment: yes all rest working well for me, the payload parameter `Authorization: XXX` creating some issue only i checked

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an invalid ETAG value in the request. I just tired this out using Postman with both valid and invalid ETAG values - with an invalid ETAG value I see the same error message:

```
{
    "Message": "{\"errorCode\":400004,\"trackingId\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-G:19-TimeStamp:05/17/2019 09:16:20\",\"message\":\"BadRequest\",\"timestampUtc\":\"2019-05-17T09:16:20.4954666Z\"}",
    "ExceptionMessage": ""
}
```

With a valid ETAG, I see the expected 204 status returned. I copied the ETAG value from the response headers I got from the "Receive Device Bound Notification" GET request.

Here is the Postman file I used:

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "f978a27b-0ad0-4e08-a38f-2749f4cd5fcb",
        "name": "IoT Hub interactions",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Receive Device Bound Notification",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "value": "SharedAccessSignature sr=XXXXXXX",
                        "description": "Generated using VS Code extension",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://MYHUB.azure-devices.net/devices/MyTestDevice/messages/deviceBound?api-version=2018-06-30",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "MYHUB",
                        "azure-devices",
                        "net"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "devices",
                        "MyTestDevice",
                        "messages",
                        "deviceBound"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "api-version",
                            "value": "2018-06-30"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/receivedeviceboundnotification"
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Complete Device Bound Notification",
            "request": {
                "method": "DELETE",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "description": "Generated using VS Code extension",
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "type": "text",
                        "value": "SharedAccessSignature sr=XXXXXXXX"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://MYHUB.azure-devices.net/devices/MyTestDevice/messages/deviceBound/{etag}?api-version=2018-06-30",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "MYHUB",
                        "azure-devices",
                        "net"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "devices",
                        "MyTestDevice",
                        "messages",
                        "deviceBound",
                        "{etag}"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "api-version",
                            "value": "2018-06-30"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/completedeviceboundnotification"
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am extracting etag from the REST `https://{{fully-qualified-iothubname}}.azure-devices.net/devices/{{device-id}}?api-version=2018-06-30` in the response i am getting a key `etag`

Comment: when I go for `Receive Device Bound Notification` then 204 is received, can you share your postman `PHP-curl`  for valid ETAG by hiding your credential.